# Passing String from angular to Spring using @Requestbody

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I am working on a project using angularjs+springboot. Am trying to send email via my application using spring-boot-starter-mail. The message and object of the email are written by the user in a form. what I want to do is to get the message and object values in my RestController using @RequestBody.

the function in my service.js

```
// send mail
                var sendMail = function(id, objet, msg) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http.post(urlBase + id, objet, msg).then(
                            function(response) {
                                deferred.resolve(response.data);
                            }, function(errResponse) {
                                console.error('Error while sending email');
                                deferred.reject(errResponse);
                            });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
```

the method in my restContoller

@RestController
public class EmailController {

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
@Autowired
UtilisateurService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendMail(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody String objet,
        @RequestBody String msg) {
    Utilisateur currentUser = service.findById(id);
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(currentUser.getEmailUtil());
    message.setSubject(objet);
    message.setText(msg);
    javaMailSender.send(message);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}}
```

This throws this exception :

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void> com.sla.utilisateur.controller.EmailController.sendMail(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

How can I fix it?

thank you,

Comment: change ResponseEntity<Void> to ResponseEntity<String>

Comment: Hi, still having the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `$http.post` is not correct.  You should have a look at the [AngularJS POST documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post). `$http.post` arguments are the following:

```
post(url, data, [config]);
```

AngularJS sends the data by default in JSON. So you should send the request using the following statement (for example):

```
$http.post(urlBase + id, {subject:objet, body:msg})
```

And in your controller you should define only one `@RequestBody` maps for the ease of the example to a  `Map` (You could change it to a POJO. ):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendMail(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody Map<String,String> msg) {
    Utilisateur currentUser = service.findById(id);
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(currentUser.getEmailUtil());
    message.setSubject(msg.get("subject");
    message.setText(msg.get("body"));
    javaMailSender.send(message);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}}
```